# D3 js Mouseover/Mouseout

Tags: d3.js

Can i use style fill and class with fill also ?

```
bar.selectAll("rect")
        .data(function(d) { return d.valores; })
        .enter().append("rect")
         .attr("class", function (d) { return ((d.star == true) ? "bar_star" : "bar"); }) //added line
        .attr("x", function (d) { return x1(d.name); })
        .attr("width", x1.rangeBand())
        .attr("y", height)
        .attr("height", 0)        
        .transition()
        .duration(500)
        .attr("y", function (d) { return y(d.value); })
        .attr("height", function (d) { return height - y(d.value); })
        .attr("value", function(d) { return d.name; })
        .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.name); }); //before

bar.on("mouseover", tip.show);
bar.on("mouseout", tip.hide);
```

My classes is :

```
.bar {
      fill: orange;
    }

.bar:hover {
  fill: orangered ;
}
```

If I try directly in the

> .on(mouseover)

it does not work.My fill is invisible.When I remove the line

> .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.name); });

Nothing works neither the tooltip nor the hover. What should I do ?

Thank you for answring,

Comment: Post a minimal WORKING example.

Comment: inline styles will take precendence over css styles